# What is the perceptron learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

In a perceptron, a neural network of one layer, what is the algorithm to update the weights and bias's? I understand that there are multiple algorithms, but is there a standard one that is easy to implement in code?

Comment: So what did you learn at wikipedia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, instead of just stating the algorithm here, I should provide some material from where you can start and quickly understand the algorithm end-to-end.

Consider this book: [Neural Networks: A Systematic Introduction](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/neuron.pdf), but Raúl Rojas.

For the Perceptron Learning, refer Section 4.2

For a very nice overview, intention, algorithm, convergence and visualisation of the space in which the learning is performed. I recommend read Chapter 3 first and then Chapter 4.

Answer (score 0):

The standard algorithm is [gradient descent using back-propagation](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html). The algorithm goes like this:

1. Guess initial weights and bias.
2. Compute the "forward pass" where you use the weight and bias to compute an estimated value `y_hat`.
3. Compute the loss, which is the difference between the true value `y` and the estimated value `y_hat` you computed from step 2.
4. Compute the gradient of the loss with respect to each of the weights and the bias. This gradient will be in the form of small floating point numbers. This step is called the "backward pass" and gives the name to "back propagation" where this gradient of the loss is pushed backwards.
5. Update the weights and bias by adding the gradients.

After you repeat steps 2 to 5 for some number of times (called epochs), you will hopefully have a the optimal weights and bias.

Comment: He does not need backpropagation for this simplified problem!

Comment: No I don't, that is only for networks with hidden layers. What I need is an explicit equation relating the old weights and bias, to the new ones.

Comment: @HarrisonRankin Wiki still gives you the complete algorithm you need. I really don't understand your reluctancy...

Comment: This answer is not really what OP is asking about - he asks for a simple perceptron algorithm, yet the answer describes gradient based mlp training (worth noting that perceptron learning, in its basic form **is not** gradient training)

Answer (score 0):

The perceptron is a linear, binary classifier. It is usually trained with the delta rule:

```
w <- initialize randomly (e.g. uniformly in [-1, 1])
learning_rate <- 0.42  # something in (0, 1)
for epoch in range(42):
    y <- perceptron_classification(x)
    w <- w - learning_rate * (y - target) * x
```

If you want to see a working (tested) minimal implementation, have a look at my repository: https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/perceptron

Comment: classical perceptron does not have learning rate, nor number of iterations, as it was designed to work only for linearly separable datasets.